# Translate expression from ternary to logical operators

Tags: typescript, logical-operators, conditional-operator

I wrote the following conditional statement using ternary operators:

```
form?.label ? (isRequired ? (form.label) : customMessage) : isRequired ? ' ' : customMessage
```

How do I write this line using logical operators only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that your code is equivalent to:

```js
isRequired ? (form.label ? form.label : ' ') : customMessage
```

which is slightly more efficient because it doesn't test `form.label` if `isRequired` is false.

Now, `form.label ? form.label : ' '` means we want `form.label`, **or** if it is false, something else. This can be written with the lazy logical **or** operator: `form.label || ' '`.

So we get:

```js
isRequired ? (form.label || ' ') : customMessage
```

In general, `c ? a : b` is equivalent to `(c && a) || b` if `a` is guaranteed to always be true. This works because the two logical operator are lazy: if `c` is false, then `a` is not evaluated because `c && a` cannot be true regardless of `b`; if `c` is `true`, then `c && a` is also true, so `b` is not evaluated because the whole conditional expression must be true regardless of `b`.

In our case, `(form.label || ' ')` is guaranteed to be true, because `' '` is true. So finally your expression becomes:

```js
(isRequired && (form.label || ' ')) || customMessage
```

Comment: I'm sure that'll help me understand how to approach this in the future. Thanks very much for your explanation!

Comment: Note that `isRequired ? (form.label ? form.label : ' ') : customMessage` is straightforward : it returns `form.label`, `' '` or `customMessage`, depending on the values of `isRequired`  and `form.label`. However, `(isRequired && (form.label || ' ')) || customMessage` is a bit deceptive: it looks like a conditional expression, yet it actually returns a string. If you want to write code that you will be able to understand at a glance when you look at it six months from now, I think the ternary operators are better suited for this than the conditional operators.